# Where can I find the Locale Information Constants in Rust's winapi crate?

Tags: winapi, rust

Are the Windows NLS API [Locale Information Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Intl/locale-information-constants) available anywhere in the [winapi-rs](https://crates.io/crates/winapi) crate or elsewhere in the Rust ecosystem?

I need to call [`GetLocaleInformationEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getlocaleinfoex) from Rust and have found it available in the `um::winnls` module of the [winapi-rs](https://crates.io/crates/winapi) crate ([here](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.6/winapi/um/winnls/fn.GetLocaleInfoEx.html)).

The `LCType` input is a [Locale Information Constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Intl/locale-information-constants) -- and I have not been able to find these defined anywhere in the crate.

As a workaround, I have looked up the numerical values and hard-coded them, but I have a nagging feeling that I am missing something.

Comment: https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.6/winapi/um/winnls/type.LCTYPE.html, that just an integer. I don't think this ressource exist in Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a late answer, but since other people can have this issue as well, so I'll still write my solution:

While the winapi crate doesn't contain all locale information constants, the windows-sys crate does.

On [this Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-information-constants) there is a list of all available Locale information constants. These are also available as constants in `windows_sys::Win32::Globalization`, see [here](https://docs.rs/windows-sys/latest/windows_sys/Win32/Globalization/index.html).

If you want to use winapi instead of windows-sys, I'd advice to just look up the value of the respective locale there and define your own constant in your Rust code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few constants defined in ntdef.rs. If you wanted to use what is not available there, you would need to look up the values via [Locale Information Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-information-constants) and either pass the raw values or preferably define them yourself.

`use self::winapi::shared::ntdef::{LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT};`

Also, be sure to configure to use winnls in Cargo.toml, or you'll get an unresolved import error when trying to use GetLocaleInformationEx.

`[dependencies]
winapi = {version = "0.3", features = ["winuser", "std", "libloaderapi", "errhandlingapi", "winnls"] }`

Comment: How can one look up the values? The values of the different constants aren't given on the link you shared.